How to Search a Column by a Substring, and return full Cell that Contains it in Excel
I need to set up a system where when I type in an ID Number in Column A, in Column B it searches Column C where I already have that ID number as a part of an email address with associated emails attached to it, delimited by commas.
[Column A: ID Number]
[Column B: Function that searches Column C by substring in Column A 
           and Returns the full cell that contains it in Column C]
[Column C: Email data associated with that ID]

For explanation: the Information I received is poorly formatted, with the ID based email mixed in randomly making it impossible to separate out for an easy VLOOKUP() type of function.

Use a lookup with wildcards.

Welcome to SO. Please provide some sample data (best by using Markdown Table Generator) - then it is much easier to helpf you.

You can use a asterisk as a wildcard for VLOOKUP and MATCH (e.g. =VLOOKUP("*est*",B:B,1,FALSE) will return the first result that contains "est" — such as "Test", "Take a rest", "established", "best friend", etc), so "easy VLOOKUP type of function" is less impossible than you think.  But, depending on what version of Excel you are using, you may want to look at the FILTER function instead…

Sample data of column A values and Column C values would be very helpful for us to craft a formula that can do this. Likely a vlookup with wildcards is the right solution.

It can be a solution for you:
[B1] =XLOOKUP("*"&A1&"*";C1:C3;C1:C3;;2)

or

[B1] =VLOOKUP("*"&A1&"*";C1:C3;1;FALSE)

Substitute "C1:C3" by the required range.
